# sum(&:x) not working any more

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sum

I use `payments.sum(&:price)` in my Rails app (4.1.2).
Since I updated from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.2, I get these errors:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
```

These variants work:

```
payments.map(&:price).sum
payments.to_a.sum(&:price)
```

Do I have to rewrite my code or do I miss something?
Thank you!

Comment: What is `payments`? Rails has two different `sum` methods: [Enumerable#sum](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) and [ActiveRecord::Relation#sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum). The first one takes a block (which is why `&`, the `to_proc` operator, works); the second doesn't. Regardless, I'm pretty sure upgrading Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.1 is a red herring. The `&` behavior did not change between those versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum):

> ## sum(*args)
>
> Calculates the sum of values on a given column. The value is returned
>   with the same data type of the column, 0 if there's no row. See
>   calculate for examples with options.
>
> ```
> Person.sum(:age) # => 4562
> ```

it seems that your code should be without the `&`:

```
payments.sum(:price)
```

Comment: This only seems to work on column names - any quick and easy way to do this with methods like how sum used to work?

Comment: @Sean if you do not use [rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), you can simply use the classic [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), like this: `payments.map(&:price).inject(:+)`

Answer (score 7):

If you had run this in Rails 4.0, you would receive the following deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #sum with a block is deprecated and will 
>   be removed in Rails 4.1. If you want to perform sum calculation over 
>   the array of elements, use ‘to_a.sum(&block)’.

This is referring to the method `Relation#sum` which previously worked in Rails 3.2 when given a block.

As others have answered, you either need to use `payments.sum(:price)` if price is a database column, or use `payments.to_a.sum(&:price)` if `price` is an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

If payments is an ActiveRecord association, you can use the [ActiveRecord::Calculations sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method instead:

```
payments.sum(:price)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` as you use it is a method on `Enumerable` module defined by Rails, not Ruby. Upgrading ruby versions should not make a difference:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

However, if you are using it to sum a column on an ActiveRecord I recommend using `sum` method on `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can do this by removing the `&`, as other answers suggest.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

The difference is that the former fetches all the records from the database, creates the objects, calls the `price` method on them and sums the results. The latter creates a SQL statement with SUM, which is much better for performance.